# In Django, why do I need to add the site name to imports in tests.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-testing

I've put some unit tests in `mysite/vncbrowser/tests.py`, and I can run these with:

```
cd mysite
python manage.py test vncbrowser
```

In `tests.py`, I import the model classes with:

```
from vncbrowser.models import Project, Stack, Integer3D, Double3D
```

... and test the insertion of an `Integer3D` into a custom field type with a test like:

```
class InsertionTest(TestCase):

    def test_stack_insertion(self):
        s = Stack()
        s.title = "Example Stack"
        s.image_base = "http://foo/bar/"
        s.dimension = Integer3D(x=2048, y=1536, z=460)
        s.resolution = Double3D(x=5.0001, y = 5.0002, z=9.0003)
        s.save()
        self.assertEqual(s.id, 1)
```

However, when I run the tests with `python manage.py test vncbrowser`, I find that a check of `isinstance(value, Integer3D)` in the `models.py` source is failing.  It seems that in the `models.py` file, the bare reference to `Integer3D` (defined earlier in that file) has the full name `vncbrowser.models.Integer3D`, while the object that is passed in from the test has the full name `mysite.vncbrowser.models.Integer3D`.

The relevant code from `models.py` with some debugging statements is:

```
class Integer3D(object):
    [... elided ...]

class Integer3DField(models.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        a = Integer3D()
        print >> sys.stderr, "value is %s, of type %s" % (value, type(value))
        print >> sys.stderr, "but a new Integer3D instance is", type(a)
        if isinstance(value, Integer3D):
            print >> sys.stderr, "isinstance check worked"
            return value
        print >> sys.stderr, "isinstance check failed"
```

... that produces this output (with some newlines and spaces added for clarity):

```
value is <vncbrowser.models.Integer3D object at 0x22bbf90>, of type
      <class 'vncbrowser.models.Integer3D'>

but a new Integer3D instance is
      <class 'mysite.vncbrowser.models.Integer3D'>

isinstance check failed
```

I can make this test work by changing the import in `tests.py` to:

```
 from mysite.vncbrowser.models import Project, Stack, Integer3D, Double3D
```

... but I don't see why the `mysite` qualification should be required in the `tests.py` file.  It doesn't seem to be required elsewhere in my django source.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but perhaps someone can explain?

(I'm not even sure why the `from mysite....` import works, in fact, since if I print `sys.path` from just before that statement, it includes the path `/home/mark/foo/mysite/`, but not `/home/mark/foo/`.)

My current working directory is `/home/mark/foo/mysite/` when I run `python manage.py test vncbrowser`.

---

As requested, the layout of my the project is as follows:

```
 ── mysite
    ├── custom_postgresql_psycopg2
    │   ├── base.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manage.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── vncbrowser
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── tables.sql
        ├── tests.py
        └── views.py
```

All of the `__init__.py` files listed above are empty.  I'm using Python 2.6.5 and Django 1.3.  I'm using Python in a virtualenv, and if I print `"\n".join(sys.path)` at the start of tests.py I get:

```
/home/mark/foo/mysite
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/distribute-0.6.10-py2.6.egg
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.6
/usr/lib64/python2.6
/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2
/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk
/home/mark/foo/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

---

*Update:* as suggested in [lbp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483198/in-django-why-do-i-need-to-add-the-site-name-to-imports-in-tests-py/7485231#7485231), I tried adding the following at the top of tests.py:

```
import vncbrowser as vnc_one
import mysite.vncbrowser as vnc_two

print "vnc_one:", vnc_one.__file__
print "vnc_two:", vnc_two.__file__
```

... which produced the output:

```
vnc_one: /home/mark/foo/mysite/vncbrowser/__init__.pyc
vnc_two: /home/mark/foo/mysite/../mysite/vncbrowser/__init__.pyc
```

Comment: When imports don't seem to work, you need to describe your physical file layout.  What directory are you in when you use `manage.py`?  What's the current working directory?  Do you have `__init__.py` files in your package directories?

Comment: @S.Lott: sorry, I've added the layout now.  I'm in the `mysite` directory when I run `manage.py` - I hoped that was indicated by the `cd mysite` near the beginning.

Comment: "indicated by the"... Explicit is better than implicit.  "Indicated by" is easy to miss.  If you want help, you need to make the conditions impossible to miss.

Comment: Final question.  Why?  Why bother checking the class of a response object?  It's a total waste of time.  The way that Django model classes are transformed into objects is not trivial, and not something you should be testing.  Why are you testing this kind of thing?

Comment: @S.Lott: my application is working with a legacy database which uses PostgreSQL compound types.  One of these is a triple of integers, and in order to pass such data to and from the database using Django's ORM, I need a custom field type.  I've done this following [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/), and the `to_python` method is called *either* with a string or an `Integer3D`.  I need to distinguish between these somehow in the `to_python` method, and the example given in the documentation for that method uses `isinstance` for that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to know all of your PYTHONPATH in order to know the one thing you actually want to know: where that *other* `vncbrowser` is coming from. Instead of printing out the python path, you can do the following:

```
import vncbrowser as vnc_one
import mysite.vncbrowser as vnc_two

print vnc_one.__file__
print vnc_two.__file__
```

And there you will see two different paths on your file system. Then you can start figuring out why.

<del>This is just a wild guess, but I think vnc_one is installed somewhere in your python path and vnc_two resides in your source code.</del> (edit: wrong guess)

Further, a random remark:

Also, you can make the import statement in tests.py simpler, by using

```
from models import ...
```

instead of

```
from XXX.models import ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've tried what you suggested, and added the results to my question.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that `/home/xxx/foo` should be in your python path, before `/home/xxx/foo/mysite`? A better solution would be to decouple your Django project from your Django app.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why it's looking in `/home/mark/foo/mysite/../` at all - that's not on `sys.path`.

Comment: That's correct, it's not on sys.path, but since mysite is probably a Django project, it contains an `__init__.py` file and thus is a Python package, so it looks for its parent directory to get its full name.

Comment: Ah, right - I think I get it.  So the package structure determines the full name of the class, and Python also looks from the top of that hierarchy for the module as well as everywhere in `sys.path`.  (If so, this is not easy to infer from [this documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-import_stmt).)  So presumably if you want to write a reusable Django application you have to be very careful only to use relative imports...

Comment: Well, you should decouple your apps from your project. Reusable Django apps are not subpackages of Django projects, but just Python packages that reside somewhere else. Both are created with `django-admin.py` I always use a specific structure, with a project and apps in the same `src` directory, which is not a python package. If you then add `..` to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, you can easily use your decoupled apps in the project and use `manage.py` from within the project directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3637/discussion-between-lbp-and-mark-longair)

Answer (score 0):

[lbp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483198/in-django-why-do-i-need-to-add-the-site-name-to-imports-in-tests-py/7485231#7485231) and comments helped me to understand and solve the problem, so that's the answer I'm accepting, but I thought it might be worth explaining in another answer where the sources of my confusion came from, since this may help other people.

When you run `manage.py`, it adds the site directory (`/home/mark/foo/mysite`, in my example) to `sys.path` before running the tests.  So, if you then import a model from `tests.py` using the import line [suggested in the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#writing-unit-tests) (which would be `from vncbrowser.models import Integer3D` in my case) and subsequently create an instance of an `Integer3D`, it will be of type `vncbrowser.models.Integer3D`, since the root of the package hierarchy is assumed to start at each entry in `sys.path`.

This name for the package is actually incorrect, however, since the application directory is nested in the site directory (as suggested by `django-admin.py` and the Django tutorial) and both of those are Python packages.  That means that the real name for the class, and the one that is valid in `models.py`, is the fully qualified `mysite.vncbrowser.models.Integer3D`.

Normally, this doesn't create a problem, since, if you're writing Python well, uses of `isinstance` [should be rare](http://www.canonical.org/~kragen/isinstance/), and duck typing means that any difference in the full name of the class of particular objects should be irrelevant.  However, when writing custom field types, you have to distinguish whether the `to_python` method has been called with a string or the object, and [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) suggests using `isinstance` for that.

To avoid this confusion in the future, as [lbp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158702/lbp) suggested in a comment, I'm now putting my applications in a separate (non-package) directory to avoid the risk of accidentally making the application dependent on the name of the site — this can easily happen with the strange default suggested hierarchy that nests application packages in the site package.